# 8x12 vs 9x13 for casserole dish?

Tags: baking

Will I need to make adjustments for cook times on something like a casserole or lasagna if using a 8x12 baking dish instead of 9x13?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to cook for a little longer because your ingredients are piled a bit deeper, but it should work more or less unmodified.

Comment: not if the dish is larger but not more deep?

Comment: @Max The depth of the dish doesn't make a difference as long as it's deep enough. The important factor is the depth of the *food*.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller dish, shorter time…

However, there's probably more variance in the oven temp & placement within it to make that much difference anyway.

With a lasagne especially, I always make the final judgement by eye. All you need is the top the right colour, everything in a lasagne is already cooked, so unless you pre-made it & are trying to cook from cold, 5 mins either way won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the dishes have the same depth, and the you put as much ingredients in them (depth wise), no.

Both lasagna and casserole are fairly forgiving in regards to baking.